# Express.js MVC structure : "Route.get() requires callback" error

Tags: node.js, express

I want to be able to access my ensureAuthenticated function (it lives in app.js) from a router and controller file.

app.js -> Application main page

feed.js -> Feed router, nothing happens here. Just URL's.

feedController.js -> Application logic is handled here. Adding, deleting, editing posts, etc.

app.js

```
exports.ensureAuthenticated = function (req, res, next) {
    next(); // does nothing atm
};
```

feed.js (just a router)

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var auth = require('../../app').ensureAuthenticated;

var feedController = require('../../controllers/frontend/feed/feedController');

router.get('/feedtest', auth, feedController.index);
module.exports = router;
```

If I move ensureAuthenticated function from app.js to feed.js, it works.

feedController.js

```
exports.index = function (req, res) {
    res.sendStatus(req.id);
};
```

Error

> Error: Route.get() requires callback functions but got a [object
>   Undefined]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be dealing with a circular dependency or [cycle](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles).

```
app.js -> feed.js -> app.js -> feed.js -> ...
```

When Node.js encounters a cycle, it will only load one of the two modules partially – up to the `require()` that starts the cycle. It'll finish loading that module, evaluating any remaining statements and updating the module cache, but not until after it's finished loading the other modules.

So, the order of the statements is now more significant within `app.js`:

```
// ...

// begins cycle, loading of `app.js` pauses here
var feed = require('./routes/feed');

// has not yet been evaluated for `feed.js` to use, so remains `undefined`
exports.ensureAuthenticated = function (req, res, next) {
    next(); // does nothing atm
};
```

Compared to:

```
// ...

// evaluated before the cycle, included within the partial
exports.ensureAuthenticated = function (req, res, next) {
    next(); // does nothing atm
};

// begins cycle, with `ensureAuthenticated` already defined
var feed = require('./routers/feed');
```

---

You can also extract `ensureAuthenticated` into a separate module (e.g. `auth.js`), that each dependent can require, and avoid the cycle entirely:

auth.js

```
// ...

exports.ensureAuthenticated = function (req, res, next) {
    next(); // does nothing atm
};
```

app.js

```
// ...


// app.js -> feed.js -> auth.js
var feed = require('./routes/feed');

// app.js -> auth.js
var auth = require('./auth');
```

feed.js

```
// ...

var auth = require('../../auth');

// ...
```